# Using an attribute specified through a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to decorate a field with an attribute that is supplied through a generic parameter of the containing class. Is this possible?

```
public class Foo<T> where T : Attribute
{
    [T]
    public float bar;    
}
```

The compiler complains that T is not an attribute class. Any chance there's a clever workaround I'm missing, or is this a no-go?

Comment: IMO it's not possible. Because for the moment the compiler tries to compile `Foo<T>` there is no specific T he can instantiate the Generic.

Comment: I believe it's impossible as attributes are static metadata. If this were allowed, one could instantiate `Foo` with a `T` not known at the time of `Foo`'s compilation, which would imply that the metadata is mutable. You might have luck with the `TypeDescriptor` and set the attribute dynamically, but I believe changes would only be reflected by using `TypeDescriptor` to use as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? I'm all for experimentation, but it smells a little like a design flaw. More detail might help you get a more helpful answer.

Comment: It's due to a quirk of Unity3D. You can use attributes on fields to customize the way they are displayed to designers. Placing one of those attributes on a collection uses the custom drawing on each individual element, instead of the collection as a whole. To draw an entire collection you have to wrap the collection in another type, which causes other annoyances. There's a janky pattern that would allow specifying an attribute on both the collection as a whole and the individual elements, but it requires being able to pass the element attribute through a generic class' type parameter.